Right to left and left to right in a sentence in from~to~ structure
How can I write the following part of a sentence so no confusion arises.

...swap from right to left to left to right...

I mean the direction of something will change from rtl to ltr.

You're worried that the ...left to left... part might be a cause of confusion? Have you tried "right-to-left" and "left-to-right"?

You could write "Reverse the direction." You aren't swapping anything.

Alternatively you could rewrite it to avoid the "to" in the middle, e.g. "replace right to left with left to right". You could even depending on context italicize or quote "right to left" and "left to right". I think asking for writing suggestions is off-topic though.

change direction from right-to-left to left-to-right

switch the direction of two things.

At the moment the direction of [movement etc] is right to left; you need to change this to left to right.

By "left to right," do you mean the writing direction used in (say) writing English? That's the only place where I've heard "LTR" used to mean "left to right."
